# Facebook Page Plugin URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When using the Facebook Page Plugin code generator, it asks for `Facebook Page URL`.  Whenever I put the correct URL in I get an error.

[image]

For the life of me, what is the correct Facebook page URL? I'm just going to my Facebook home page and coping the URL and its giving me this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a Facebook **fan page** not a **personal profile**.

- facebook.com/facebook <- fan page
- facebook.com/zuck <- personal profile

For personal profiles use the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't say anything about fan page vs personal pages.